# Salesforce Marketing Cloud: Fetching of push messages from Backend

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, marketingcloudapi

We have been sending a lot of push notifications (millions every day) via AWS SNS based on triggers in our backend services and quite a lot of push notifications (millions every month) via Salesforce Marketing Cloud based on the data we have there. Now we are trying to build an inbox in the app for both.

We were able to successfully fetch push messages from the Salesforce SDK directly to the app, however, as we want to show both pushes that were sent via Salesforce and from our internal backend services (so via SNS), we would prefer to fetch those pushes via Salesforce API in the backend and merge both data sources there before returning it to the frontend clients (iOS and Android).

Fetching messages via SDK in mobile was quite simple, however in the backend I struggle to find an appropriate endpoint. The best I have found so far is [retrieveAllPushMessages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/references/mc_rest_push/retrieveAllPushMessages.html), however it returns messages in the rough form (for example: `%%=ContentBlockByKey(\"4324a4b3-....-....-....-....\")=%%%%=TreatAsContent(@title)=%%`) as we use AMPscript to make dynamic content in our messages. This is something we cannot really process in the backend. On top of that I was not able to find any endpoint nor filter that would allow me to fetch messages for a specific user (contact ID), which is also a bit problematic.

Coinciding that in SDK it is possible to get messages that are ready to be presented to the customers - [inbox-message-manager/index.html](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/javadocs/MarketingCloudSdk/8.0/com.salesforce.marketingcloud.messages.inbox/-inbox-message-manager/index.html) - is there a way that the appropriate API exist, but is not documented?

Answer (score 0):

How were you able to fetch push messages from the Salesforce SDK directly to the app?
Were you able to show these in the SFMC mobile inbox?

To answer your question, depending on how personalised your messages are:

If message are highly personalised: you would need to sendlog push messages (or write to a  specific logging Data extension), including title and message content, then retrieve records from the Sendlog or specific DE using the Retrieve Data extension row REST route.

If messages are not personalised, then you could potentially get away with logging Contact key and messageid to avoid retrieving so much data